# Cannot read subscribe of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I try to get information on authentication from the Service and get this problem:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

the code of the service:

```
user:any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private http:HttpClient,private router: Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user=>{
      this.user = user;
    });
    console.log(this.afAuth.authState);
   }

   userinfo(){
     return this.user;
   }
```

the code of the component:

```
user:any
  constructor(public afAuth:AuthService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.userinfo().subscribe(userinfo =>{
      this.user = userinfo;
    })
    console.log(this.user.uid);
  }
```

where I am wrong here? and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `userinfo` returns a `User`, and not an Observable, so it doesn't have a `subscribe` method.

I would change the AuthService to

```
user: Observable<User>;
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private http:HttpClient,private router: Router) {
  this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
}
```

Additionally, reconsider why you always try to store the latest value in a property, both in the Service and in the Component. Angular philosophy is to use connected `Observables` to generate values.